# How do I use GitHub through harsh proxies?

Tags: git, github

Given the following constraints, how can I use GitHub from Windows and Unix?

- All access to the internet is restricted to a proxy
- The proxy only allows connections out on port 80 and 443
- CONNECT method is only enabled for 443
- Proxy Authentication is required (NTLM or Basic)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See a [“Using Github Through Draconian Proxies (Windows And Unix)”](http://tachang.tumblr.com/post/22265579539/using-github-through-draconian-proxies-windows-and) by Jeff Tchang (formerly available from [another location](http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html)), which includes instructions for both Windows and Unix platforms, summarized below.

#### Unix

1. Download Git.
2. Download and install [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/).
3. Edit or create the file `~/.ssh/config` and put the following:

   > ```
   > ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew proxy.example.com 443 %h %p ~/.ssh/myauth
   >
   > Host github.com
   > User git
   > Port 22
   > Hostname github.com
   > IdentityFile "/media/truecrypt1/Keys/GitHubKey.private"
   > TCPKeepAlive yes
   > IdentitiesOnly yes
   >
   > Host ssh.github.com
   > User git
   > Port 443
   > Hostname ssh.github.com
   > IdentityFile "/media/truecrypt1/Keys/GitHubKey.private"
   > TCPKeepAlive yes
   > IdentitiesOnly yes
   > ```
4. If everything is setup correctly you should be able to run `ssh github.com` and see

   > Hi user! You’ve successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
   >   Connection to github.com closed.

   If this doesn’t work you can run `ssh ssh.github.com` and get the exact same thing. If the first command didn’t work it means you are using a proxy that blocks CONNECT on port 22. Almost no proxies block CONNECT on port 443 because you need that for SSL.

#### Windows

1. Download [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Some settings:

   - “Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt”
   - “Use OpenSSH” (this one is very important)
   - Pick your line endings
2. Download [connect.c](http://bent.latency.net/bent/darcs/goto-san-connect-1.85/src/connect.html). This tool deserves its own post mostly because of its utter simplicity. It mirrors the open source tool corkscrew and is used for tunneling through proxies. Yes the tool’s name is really called “connect.c.” For Windows users, a pre-compiled binary is available. I put my `connect.exe` in `C:\Windows\connect.exe`.
3. Decide whether you like to use the Windows `cmd.exe` to do stuff or the Cygwin style shell. Or both.
4. Set up the Cygwin Git bash shell.

   For the Cygwin style shell start up the Git icon and edit the file `~/.ssh/config` and make sure the file has no extension. Put the following in that file, and note how the paths are specified.

   > ```
   > ProxyCommand /c/windows/connect.exe -H username@proxy.example.com:443 %h %p
   >
   > Host github.com
   > User git
   > Port 22
   > Hostname github.com
   > IdentityFile "/c/Keys/GitHubKey.private"
   > TCPKeepAlive yes
   > IdentitiesOnly yes
   >
   > Host ssh.github.com
   > User git
   > Port 443
   > Hostname ssh.github.com
   > IdentityFile "/c/Keys/GitHubKey.private"
   > TCPKeepAlive yes
   > IdentitiesOnly yes
   > ```
5. Set up the Windows `cmd.exe` shell.

   Suppose you don’t like the Git Bash shell. You prefer the cmd.exe interpreter.

   - Go to your config file at `C:\Documents and Settings\.ssh\config`
   - Make a copy of it or make a new one. I called mine `config-windows`

   Put the following in the file, again paying careful attention to path separators and styles.

   > ```
   > ProxyCommand C:/Windows/connect.exe -H username@proxy.example.com:443 %h %p
   >
   > Host github.com
   > User git
   > Port 22
   > Hostname github.com
   > IdentityFile "C:\Keys\GitHubKey.private"
   > TCPKeepAlive yes
   > IdentitiesOnly yes
   >
   > Host ssh.github.com
   > User git
   > Port 443
   > Hostname ssh.github.com
   > IdentityFile "C:\Keys\GitHubKey.private"
   > TCPKeepAlive yes
   > IdentitiesOnly yes
   > ```

For full details, see [the full blog post](http://tachang.tumblr.com/post/22265579539/using-github-through-draconian-proxies-windows-and).

Comment: I would like to add that for NTLM authentication you can use CNTLM. Most corporate proxies allow basic auth but some are really really restrictive and only allow NTLM.

Comment: Found it here: http://tachang.tumblr.com/post/22265579539/using-github-through-draconian-proxies-windows-and

Comment: `connect.exe` is installed as part of msysgit. It was included in [February of 2010](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/commit/7b1870d634e7672abbbd2f528cb66fc2c4b8a431).

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 4):

[Since my addition to the first answer given above did not get approved within four days, I put it here.]

Note that `corkscrew` and `connect`, as well as the standard Unix command `nc` only support basic authentication (which insecurely transmits the password).
[`tunnel-auth` version 0.04](http://David.von-Oheimb.de/perlen/tunnel-auth) in addition supports digest authentication.

In case your proxy requires NTLM authentication, all these commands may be combined very nicely with [`cntlm`](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) as follows:

Choose a local port (e.g, 8080 as in the examples below) on which `cntlm` will listen
(performing the user authentication with the proxy and forwarding any
further packages to/from the proxy), set the port etc. (e.g., in
`/etc/cntlm.conf`), and use instead of the ProxyCommand given above (with the respective port number inserted):

> ProxyCommand corkscrew 127.0.0.1 8080 %h %p

or

> ProxyCommand connect -H 127.0.0.1:8080 %h %p

or

> ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x 127.0.0.1:8080 %h %p

or

> ProxyCommand tunnel-auth -p 127.0.0.1:8080 -r %h:%p

Answer (score 2):

My scenario was a little different to Jeff Tchang's (but based on his post) but might be helpful here.

All of our workplace/corporate internet access is via a non-authenticating proxy. I was able to clone *from* but not push *to* github: running

```
git push -u origin master
```

would return

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Based on http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html and http://meinit.nl/ssh-through-a-proxy-from-your-apple-mac-os-x and http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php I was able to download/install corkscrew and add the following to my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host github.com
  User git
  Port 22
  Hostname github.com
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy.<my-workplace>.com 8080 %h %p
```

Some points to note:

- I use my workplace/corporate private key also with GitHub: if you don't you will need to add an "IdentityFile" line
- Unlike with Jeff Tchang (and thanks to mtu.net) I did not need to have the "~/.ssh/myauth" at the end of the ProxyCommand line
- I did not need to set up a ssh.github.com Host section.

Hope these help.