# Git through digest proxy authentication

Tags: git, proxy

I want to do "git clone" through a proxy server. The issue is my proxy server uses digest authentication. So i can't find neither in git documentation, nor help that someone that already made.

I dig through google search and i can't find any helpful results.

Thxs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just to save a few moments of googling on Bennet's Answer:

1. Clear old settings:
   `>git config --global --unset https.proxy`
   `>git config --global --unset http.proxy`
2. Set new settings:
   `>git config --global https.proxy https://USER:PWD@proxy.whatever:80`
   `>git config --global http.proxy http://USER:PWD@proxy.whatever:80`
3. Verify new settings:
   `>git config --get https.proxy`
   `>git config --get http.proxy`

NOTE: When you verify, you should see the same values that you put in.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to do a git clone through an authenticated proxy by setting the environment variable `http_proxy` to `http://username:password@proxyhost:80`

Then a plain ole `git clone` worked.

(The proxy is some corporate Windows thing, so my username actually looked like domain\username. Took a while to realise that I needed the domain.)

Comment: sweet - worked a treat for me. Thanks for solving this long-standing issue for me :)

Comment: What if the username contains \ and . ?

Comment: No problem. As I mentioned, my username contains a backslash.

Comment: Worked for me too but... if you're cloning from an https repository, set the environment variable 'https_proxy' instead / as well.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Git does support http proxies since [Git 1.7.10, Apr. 2012, commit dd61399](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd6139971a18e25a5089c0f96dc80e454683ef0b).

But, that supposes you have curl 7.10.7+ installed, which is something Git wasn't checking before Git 2.3.2+ (Q1 2015)

This is fixed with [commit 1c2dbf2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c2dbf2095beb5227d963a1541e356bd2e834dff) by [Tom G. Christensen (`tgc`)](https://github.com/tgc)

http: support curl < 7.10.7

> [Commit dd61399](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd6139971a18e25a5089c0f96dc80e454683ef0b) introduced support for http proxies that require authentication but it relies on the `CURL_PROXYAUTH` option which was
>   added in curl 7.10.7.
>   This makes sure proxy authentication is only enabled if libcurl can support it.

Answer (score 3):

Using

> git config --global http.proxy

or more in general, 
if the user or password has any special char like "$\" etc you gotta url encode it making then something like: %24%5C

hope this will help as I usually get mad about this...

Answer (score 1):

Git does not appear to support authenticated proxy servers. You can check [`http.c` from the git.git repository](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=http.c;hb=HEAD); in order to support authenticated proxy servers at all, it would have to set [`CURL_PROXYUSERPWD`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROXYUSERPWD) to set the username and password, but that string does not appear in that file.

One possible solution would be to fix Git; add a few more configuration parameters to `http.c`, such as `http.proxyuser`, `http.proxypass`, to set the username and password for the proxy, and `http.proxyauth` to set the authentication method, and then pass those in as the appropriate [cURL configuration options](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).

If you don't feel like hacking on the Git source code, you could set up your own, local proxy server, that needs no authentication, and then forward from that to the proxy server that requires authentication. <s>[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) supports [this mode of operation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/), though the configuration can be a little complex; I found [an example configuration](http://nongraphical.com/2008/11/updated-squid-3-configuration/) that purports to demonstrate this setup, though I haven't verified that it works myself.</s>

**edit**: Never mind, after checking the [Squid source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#GUxBL_cNJpE/src/http.c&q=package:squid%20%22-%3Elogin%22%20package:%22cvs%20:pserver:anoncvs@cvs.squid-cache.org:/squid%20squid%22&sa=N&cd=5&ct=rc&l=1167), it appears to only support Basic authentication, not Digest authentication, when forwarding requests to a peer:

```
httpHeaderPutStrf(hdr_out, header, "Basic %s", base64_encode(orig_request->peer_login));
```

I haven't found any proxy servers that can pass a request along to another proxy with digest authentication enabled; if you can find one that supports digest auth for an upstream proxy, I'd recommend using that.

Otherwise, I'd recommend using a different protocol than HTTP; use `ssh:` if you need authentication, or the raw `git:` protocol if you're just pulling changes down from a public server.

Comment: Yes, I'm recommending that you set up Squid as a local proxy server (on the same machine that Git is running on), with no authentication, and have Squid connect to your proxy server that has authentication. Then just configure Git to use your local Squid as its proxy server.

Comment: Thxs you, very much (trying to reach 15 chars).

Comment: Sorry, I realized that Squid doesn't support that usage; it only supports basic auth for upstream proxies, not digest. Added some more recommendations.

Comment: Have you sent the patch upstream? I'd recommend that, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you're cloning over SSH, the answer to the closely related question [How do I use GitHub through harsh proxies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040089/how-do-i-use-github-through-harsh-proxies) looks adaptable to your situation, but instead of [Corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/), which doesn't yet support digest authentication, use [`tunnel-auth.pl`](http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TE/TECHNIK/tunnel-auth.pl) from CPAN.