# SSH in git behind proxy on windows 7

Tags: windows, git, ssh, proxy

I am testing SSH connection for checking RSA key in git.
I am working over proxy server.
I am using window 7 and have installed msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.
Now in msys.exe window i have set proxy by command 'git config --global http.proxy http://host:port' 
After that i have tried command 'ssh git@github.com' .
This gives me error like 'ssh: github.com: no address associated with name'

What should i do?

Answer (score 67):

Setting `http.proxy` will not work for ssh. You need to proxy your ssh connection. See [this](http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html) description. To summarize:

Start `git-cmd.bat` and create `~/.ssh/config` (`notepad %home%\.ssh\config.`)

```
ProxyCommand /bin/connect.exe -H proxy.server.name:3128 %h %p

Host github.com
  User git
  Port 22
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile "C:\users\username\.ssh\id_rsa"
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host ssh.github.com
  User git
  Port 443
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  IdentityFile "C:\users\username\.ssh\id_rsa"
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

(set the correct proxy hostname:port, and the path to id_rsa. When you use git-bash, use slashes in the path to id_rsa)
(My version of [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) includes `connect.exe`, so I do not need to download and compile [connect.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731110457/http://www.meadowy.org/~gotoh/ssh/connect.c)). A precompiled exe is also available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130516045959/http://www.meadowy.org/~gotoh/ssh/connect.exe).

Now `ssh github.com` should work

Note that if you want to connect via a socks5 proxy, then change `-H` to `-S`.

```
ProxyCommand connect -S proxy.server.name:1080 %h %p
```

If you use a Linux file system, the file permission of `~/.ssh/config` must be 600, but on a standard NTFS windows partition, these kind of permissions do not exist.

If your proxy requires NTLM authentication, you can use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/), see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343300/33499).

Comment: It works fine, as long as `~/.ssh/config` has the right permission. But the way, it's a pity that the answer is correct but not accepted yet.

Comment: On my system connect.exe was installed in a different location.  To get it to work I had to set ProxyCommand "/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" -S proxy.server.name:1234 %h %p (note I am using SOCKS5 not http so I changed the H to S)

Comment: That **connect.exe** link has been dead. Does anybody know an alternative link?

Comment: Thanks @wimh. I also found it in my windows machine at **C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\connect.exe** that Git for Windows 64bit is installed.

Comment: This answer with **connect.exe** works fine but it seems not to support the password for socks5 proxy. My socks must need both ID and Password in addition to ssh ID & Password. I'd like to use like `ProxyCommand connect -S ID:PASSWORD@proxy.server.name:1080 %h %p` but it gets an error.  `ProxyCommand connect -S ID@proxy.server.name:1080 %h %p` works well but typing a password every time is annoying.

Comment: I cannot comment here, so I create this answer which should be comment for wimh For git bash on Window, please change /bin/connect.exe to connect.exe Anyway, thank for great info.

Comment: In GitBash, I used the `connect.exe` in the link but got error `syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'  <!DOCTYPE html>  Connection closed by remote host`. After I changed to `"/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe"`, it works well.

Comment: With latest official Windows Git version, I had to use `ProxyCommand connect.exe -H proxy.server.name:3128 %h %p` (`connect.exe` is bundled in git's `mingw64\bin` directory which seems to be added in the path when running a `git` command)

Answer (score -2):

Does your proxy require a password? Then it might be that.

`export http_proxy="http://<domain>\<username>:<password>@<server>:<port>"`

See : [How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128035/119790) (duplicate!)