# OpenShift: Cannot create application without -from-code

Tags: deployment, ssh, openshift, web-deployment

I'm trying to create a new OpenShift application using Linux Ubuntu Gnome. When I do this using `rhc app create someName`, I get the following error: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`.

I tried all the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518074/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic-on-openshift) but nothing has worked.

When I use the command `rhc app create meteor nodejs-0.10 mongodb-2 --from-code=https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-meteorjs-quickstart.git`
 as described [here](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-meteorjs-quickstart) (my application is a meteor application), there is no error and I can subsequently push to OpenShift.

Because using the second method has other disadvantages for me, I would like to use the first one. Has anyone any idea (other than the ones described in the thread I linked to) what I could do? And why it works when using -from-source?

Comment: In the first example, you do not provide a cartridge, is that correct?  You have to provide a web cartridge to use from the rhc cartridges list.  Can you verify that you are indeed passing in a cartridge?

Comment: Yes. I just left that out for brevity

Comment: What version of rhc are you using? rhc --version should get that for you, the current version is 1.30.2, also make sure you are using a recent version of ruby, maybe at least 1.9.x

Comment: I newly installed rhc so that should be fine. But I'll check later

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.1.2 and the newest version of rhc.

Comment: have you run rhc setup?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using linux. I stated all over again (delete all relevant files etc) and now it works.