# Can't fetch from private repository with EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, proxy, egit, java-io

I am trying to synchronise my eclipse java project with my private git repository using EGit plug-in but I'm being unsuccessful. 
I have configured the remote origin as:

URI: git@github.com:username/project.git

Host: github.com

Repository path: username/project.git

Unfortunately, when I try to fetch, I get this error:

> git@github.com:Maslor/wfmgr.git: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: >Forbidden
>   git@github.com:Maslor/wfmgr.git: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: >Forbidden
>   git@github.com:Maslor/wfmgr.git: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: >Forbidden

I am using a proxy, does that mean I have to configure EGit's proxy settings, if there are any? How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

There is a pending issue: [bug 349702 EGit tries to use HTTP proxy for SSH connect](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349702).

If you don't need the proxy when connecting to ssh, try and remove said proxy.
Or use a proxy bypass, as [illustrated in this bug report](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-14304).

[image: https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12362176/12362176_bypass-proxy.png]

If not, try an https url (provided you have a username/password associated to the remote repo server)

Comment: Should I use the exemplified host  (`stgas71-domodossola.stg.rhcloud.com`) or should I use my network's proxy host? @VonC

Comment: @Maslor your own host (to be bypassed). The picture is just an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ssh git@github.com` to first see if it is a problem with your IDE or also global to your system.

I then suggest you to follow this : [SSH in git behind proxy on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103083/problem-of-testing-ssh-in-git-behind-proxy-on-window-7)

Comment: I did try that but it wouldn't work, though I will try it again as you are recommending. My main issue with that method is that it usually implies that I have my git password exported, revealing it in a text file.

Comment: I don't see where your github password should be exported ? Does `ssh git@github.com` work ?