# SSH in git behind proxy on windows - FATAL: Connection closed by peer

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, bitbucket, git-bash

By a **SSH connection**, I'm trying to clone a Repository from a Company BitBucket which use 7999 port (not Bitbucket.org) using **Git Bash**. I've generated the RSA key and added the public key into my profile of the BitBucket Company and the keys re located in `~/.ssh`, I've setup the proxy by using `git config --global http.proxy http://userPrx:pwdPrx@ipProx:8080` (because I'm under the Company Proxy) and also I have setup my `config` file as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103083/ssh-in-git-behind-proxy-on-windows-7) suggest. Then, when I try to *Test* the connection I get this:

```
$ ssh -vT globaldevtools -p 7999
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for globaldevtools
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /C/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe -S IpProxy:8080 x.x.x.x 7999
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1104711
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
FATAL: Connection closed by peer.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This is my `config` file:

```
ProxyCommand /C/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe -S IpProxy:8080 %h %p


Host globaldevtools
  User git
  Port 7999
  Hostname x.x.x.x
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I must indicate that in this file (`config`) instead of `IpProxy:8080` I've tried with

```
http://IpProxy:8080
http://usrProx:pwdProx@IpProxy:8080
usrProx:pwdProx@IpProxy:8080
```

Do I have to do something else? Did I miss something? All help is appreciated.