# How to Setup Corkscrew to Connect to Github through Draconian Proxy

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

My company has a draconian proxy server that prevents me from SSHing to remove servers, and therefore preventing me from using github. I have spent the last day following examples on the web, such as

- [How do I use GitHub through harsh proxies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040089/how-do-i-use-github-through-harsh-proxies)
- http://tachang.tumblr.com/post/22265579539/using-github-through-draconian-proxies-windows-and

But nothing seems to be working. Here is my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy02.COMPANY_NAME.com 8080 %h %p

Host github.com
User git
Port 22
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile "/Users/msnider/.ssh/id_rsa"
IdentitiesOnly yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

Host ssh.github.com
User git
Port 443
Hostname ssh.github.com
IdentityFile "/Users/msnider/.ssh/id_rsa"
IdentitiesOnly yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

This is the error message I receive when I try to `git pull --rebase`:

```
Proxy could not open connnection to github.com:  Forbidden
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I get the same forbidden error when I just try to SSH to github.com, but I can ssh to ssh.github.com if I specify my identity:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@ssh.github.com
Hi mattsnider! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to ssh.github.com closed.
```

There is no authentication needed to connect to the proxy server.

I have also tried setting the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy02.COMPANY_NAME.com:8080
https_proxy=http://proxy02.COMPANY_NAME.com:8080
```

Anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong and how I can get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I have finally figured it out. My company's proxy server blocks all communication on ports other than 80 and 443, so I cannot connect to github on port 22. I thought the examples I found on the web were to change communication from 22 to 443, but they do not.

The problem is with this section of code from all the web examples:

```
Host github.com
User git
Port 22
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile "/Users/msnider/.ssh/id_rsa"
IdentitiesOnly yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

This says when connecting to github.com from the proxy server use the hostname github.com and port 22, which is blocked by my proxy. By changing the `github.com` definition to:

```
Host github.com
User git
Port 443
Hostname ssh.github.com
IdentityFile "/Users/msnider/.ssh/id_rsa"
IdentitiesOnly yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

I can finally connect to github.