# Working on two different Git Organization repos using two different credentials in proxy mode

Tags: git, github, ssh, proxy, ssh-keys

Guys i really need to sort things up, as i am working with two different organizations  with two github accounts. I want to work in both of them independently without mixing the two id's. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain), which works fine.

But now the issue is i am working on a linux system where i am behind a proxy server. So i have to use corkscrew to use ssh on my system.

I've already added this line to `~./ssh/config`:

```
Host * ProxyCommand corkscrew <proxy ip address> 8080 %h %p
```

Now i am confused to follow the link i've mentioned as it works for ideal condition.

I am really stucked here. Please can somebody help in this one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you mention uses the default port (22).
If you are using corkscrew, it is likely that all ports are blocked but 80 and 443 (http and https).

So you need to add the right `Port 443` to your `~/.ssh/config`, as [illustrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21320829/6309).